# Lost Bitcoin from Bitcoin-core after resetting PC

Tags: bitcoin-core, lost-bitcoins, lost-wallet

The other day I reset my PC and I have lost all my BTC. Is there any way I can get it back? (using Bitcoin core)

Comment: Could you be more specific what you did when you "reset" the computer?

Comment: about a week ago

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "reset"?

Comment: I messed up my gpu overclock which put me on bluescreen upon start-up so I did a windows reset but kept files and when it reloaded I had to re-sync  bitcoin core and the wallet was no longer there

Comment: If you lost your wallet.dat file, and have no backup, your coins are gone.

Answer (score -2):

It is extremely simple to get your BTC back. Simply fetch one of your backup disks/USB sticks which you have hidden around your home, containing redundant copies of any important data.